# How to handle & and + characters in hyperlinks in the search People hover panel template

Tags: javascript, search-results, hyperlink, display-template, managed-property

In our SP Server 2013 environment we have an employee directory. The hover panel that shows up next to a result shows the Department name of an employee. This is a clickable hyperlink. When a user clicks on it, he's being taken to a new search results page with the Department name as the query.

Problem is:

The Department name contains characters such as `&` or `+`. When the link is clicked, everything after the `&` is gone. Or, in case of the `+`, the `+` sign is removed. This results in incorrect search results.

I checked the code in the People hover panel display template and it says (Afdeling means Department):

```
<div class="ms-srch-hover-text" id="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Department =#_">Afdeling: <a href="?k=department:_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Department =#_">_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Department =#_</a></div>
```

In the search engine, when a user clicks on the Department name in the hover panel, the resulting url being created is:

```
rootdomain/zoeken/Paginas/peopleresults.aspx?k=department:P&I/L&M/SASO/SASOB
```

( `P&I/L&M/SASO/SASOB` is the Department name).

I think the Department code should be in double quotation marks (`""`) to ensure it processes the entire Department name as the query, not just what's before the `&` character.

How can I fix this in the display template? Or should something else be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your browser thinks you are adding querystring parameters. In order to make it work, you will have to encode the department names. The "&" ampersands should become this "%26".

The encoding of your departments can be done by using the following JavaScript function:

```
encodeURIComponent(departmentName)
```

So in your example you can write the HTML like this:

```
<div class="ms-srch-hover-text" id="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Department =#_">Afdeling: <a href="?k=department:_#= encodeURIComponent(ctx.CurrentItem.Department) =#_">_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Department =#_</a></div>
```

The URL will be encoded like this:

```
?k=department:P%26I%2FL%26M%2FSASO%2FSASOB
```